# is it Possible to Pull the report of Azure AD connect server Synchronization Service status using PowerShell Script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-connect

I need the pull the report using PowerShell script of recent AAD connect Synchronization service connector operation status of "Full Synchronization", "Full Import" and "Delta Synchronization" of all connectors.

instead of RDP the server every day and check the status, is it possible to pull the report and send to my mail using a service account.

"**This Report I need to pull using script**"

[image]

Comment: Try with `Get-ADSyncToolsRunHistory` or even better `Export-ADSyncToolsRunHistory -Path .\RunHistory-RunStep.xml`

Comment: can we specify only the latest "Full Synchronization" , "Full Import" , "Delta Synchronization"  and "Delta Import" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available options are `Get-ADSyncToolsRunHistory`
[image]

Or if you want to export the output in XML format `Export-ADSyncToolsRunHistory -Path .\RunHistory-RunStep.xml`
[image]

All the ADSyncTools PowerShell commands are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-adsynctools)

Comment: Thank you @SoySolisCarlos for the guide its helpful , I got the expected output.